# WKWebView loadData alternative for displaying NSData in iOS 8 (Except UIWebView)

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I would like to know if there are any alternatives to the `loadData` (iOS 9 only) function of `WKWebView` without using it's older brother `UIWebView`.

Maybe there's a way to display document files (xlsx,docx,pptx,pdf,images) using the `loadHTMLString` like how I display audio or video files in my code below.

It has to be able to accept `NSData` because the file is encrypted at all times in the disk, so `loadRequest` is not possible

Below is my code for viewing files:

```
if ( mimeType == kMimeTypeVideo || mimeType == kMimeTypeAudio ) {
    NSString *contentType = [MIMETypeToFileExtViceVersaConverter convertFileExtensionToMimeType:shareWithObject.fileExtension];

    NSString *base64String = [fileData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" \
                     <html><head></head><body style=\"margin:0;width:100%%;height:100%%;\">\
                     <video controls height=\"100%%\" width=\"100%%\"> \
                     <source type=\"%@\" src=\"data:%@;base64,%@\"> \
                     </video></body></html>", contentType, contentType, base64String];

    [_webView loadHTMLString:str baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
} else {
    NSString *contentType = [MIMETypeToFileExtViceVersaConverter convertFileExtensionToMimeType:shareWithObject.fileExtension];

    [_webView loadData:fileData MIMEType:contentType characterEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no other way as of now than to use `UIWebView`.

And to add to the troubles of using the `loadData` function of `WKWebView`, it has very limited support in the files that it can view, like how it can't load doc/docx and ppt/pptx files.

In conclusion, don't use `WKWebView` if you are thinking of making it the default viewer of the your `NSData` converted documents.